# Copy to Clipboard - copying code

Tags: clipboard

I am using copy to clipboard and it works perfectly with regular text, but not with copying code.  The code I am trying to copy is a font awesome code that you'll see in the text below.  It copies a square instead of the code I entered for it to copy.

I'll also need to do the copy to clipboard with the style tag attribute

```js
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2016 Milan Kyncl
 * Licensed under the MIT license.
 *
 * jquery.copy-to-clipboard plugin
 * https://github.com/mmkyncl/jquery-copy-to-clipboard
 *
 */

$.fn.CopyToClipboard = function() {
    var textToCopy = false;
    if(this.is('select') || this.is('textarea') || this.is('input')){
        textToCopy = this.val();
    }else {
        textToCopy = this.text();
    }
    CopyToClipboard(textToCopy);
};

function CopyToClipboard( val ){
    var hiddenClipboard = $('#_hiddenClipboard_');
    if(!hiddenClipboard.length){
        $('body').append('<textarea style="position:absolute;top: -9999px;" id="_hiddenClipboard_"></textarea>');
        hiddenClipboard = $('#_hiddenClipboard_');
    }
    hiddenClipboard.html(val);
    hiddenClipboard.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
}

$(function(){
    $('[data-clipboard-target]').each(function(){
        $(this).click(function() {
            $($(this).data('clipboard-target')).CopyToClipboard();
        });
    });
    $('[data-clipboard-text]').each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            CopyToClipboard($(this).data('clipboard-text'));
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-clipboard-text="&#xf067;">Copy</button>
```

Comment: This is because font-awesome isn't a system font --  You won't be able to copy the "symbol" unless that "font" is installed on your system .. It'll just be a "unknown character" and display as a "square"

Comment: Even if I want to copy the code..not the icon itself.  I want to copy the  "&#xf067;" to the clipboard

Answer (score 0):

Some characters are reserved in HTML.
If you use the less than **(<)** or greater than **(>)** signs in your text, the browser might mix them with tags.
Character entities are used to display reserved characters in HTML.
A character entity looks like this:

> &entity_name; OR &#entity_number;

To display a less than sign **(<)** we must write: `&lt;` or `&#60;`

so if you want to add your font awesome code in html should to convert it to HTML Entities 
Example : your code above is `&#xf067;`   if you want insert it in html then any one copy it as a code should be like this `&amp;#xf067;`

```
 &#xf067; = &amp;#xf067;
```

here is an image for some HTML Entities  may help you 
https://gulfupload.com/i/00025/bvlhjmdnfd6x.png
 i hope it helps you